# http not redirecting to https://www in nginx | using apache and nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, http, 301-redirect

Non www version redirects to nginx default page instead of website how can I fix this?

- `https://www.example.com` works fine,
- `http://www.example.com` works fine,
- `https://example.com` works fine,

But `http://example.com` don't work people get to the default nginx page instead of website

Here is my nginx config file:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /var/www/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /var/www/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

My issue is I can't seem to make it redirect from `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` instead showing nginx standard page.

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

I tried this as well and still not working.

P.S. Also I am using apache to with nginx in combination

How can I fix?

Comment: You have only posted the top level configuration file. Where are the server blocks for your website?

Comment: no i only have this and the 2 apache configs /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: @Richard Smith thanks i fixed i completely forgot about the server blocks... thanks mate

Comment: If you use **nginx** and **Apache**, which one is running on which port? Run: `ss -tlp state listening '( sport :http or sport :https )'` as root.